# InputStream to byte array

Tags: java, caching, inputstream, outputstream

I have this code:

```
  private static void flow(InputStream is, OutputStream os, byte[] buf)
      throws IOException {
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
      os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
  }
```

Which basically streams from `is` to the `OutputStream` provided.
My goal is to cache the `is` when the flow has completed.

As such I have:

`cacheService.cache(key, bytes);`

Comment: Wirte to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` the same way you write to `os` (maybe even in the same loop if you still want to write to `os` too) and then call `toByteArray` to get the result. Note that this can obviously result in a huge `byte[]` if `is` provides a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to implement a Caching output stream:

```
public class CachingOutputStream extends OutputStream {
  private final OutputStream os;
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  public CachingOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
    this.os = os;
  }

  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    try {
      os.write(b);
      baos.write(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if(e instanceof IOException) {
        throw e;
      } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public byte[] getCache() {
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    os.close();
  }

  public void flush() throws IOException {
    os.flush();
  }
}
```

And do this:

```
final CachingOutputStream cachingOutputStream = new CachingOutputStream(outputStream);
flow(inputStream, cachingOutputStream, buff);
cached = cachingOutputStream.getCache();
if(cached != null) {
  cacheService.put(cacheKey, cached);
}
```

Comment: Alternative pre-made solution: `org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;` from Apache Commons/

Answer (score 0):

Using  org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils,

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```